# idhttp : password changes with each login using a loginkey

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, indy, indy10, idhttp

I have already successfully logged in many sites using idhttp.post() but this particular site has a bit different login process
After analyzing the site using http analyzer i can see that at the user, pass part, the username is what i have sent, but the password is a coded password and there is something like a login key there as well
i used inspect element and i noticed that it seems the password is coded using the login key
anyway, the point is that i cant login because the password is dynamic !
i should mention that at the html source i can parse the login key if that is something that is necessary but after that i don't know what should i do
**Edit :**
for privacy reasons i can not provide the url for the site but here are some information :
**site is :**
http://somesite.net/user.php
**Http analyzer post data when i sign in to the site:**

```
Parameter Name  Value                             
module          User                              
op              login                             
backUrl         1                                 
loginKey        1750486858  // this key can be parsed if i get the source for the signin page                      
url                                               
uname           someusername                         
pass            efa47b543e84d834162c0cc2cd257e56
```

**a few facts :**
1- each time i refresh the site **loginKey** changes and when i login again pass is different too
2- i send the post data as it is but it redirects me to a 404 error page
3 -**some of Html source:**

```
<td width="50%" class="loginBorder">
                <table id="userUndefineLogin" style="display:none;width:100%; margin-top: 0px;">
                    <form action="http://somesite/user.php" method="post" onsubmit="return encryptPassword('pass1');">
                    <input type="hidden" name="module" value="User" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="op" value="login" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="backUrl" value="1" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="loginKey" id="loginKey" value="14733929" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="" />
```

thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should ask the owner/publisher of the web site how to login programmatically. How can you possibly think that somebody here would be able to answer this question.

Comment: @Tom Brunberg, how can you be sure that it can't be done when you do not have enough information or have not encounter such a problem, please do no give negative score just because you do not understand the question or can not answer it, i also should mention that if a browser can do it, then idHttp can as well, so it should be doable

Comment: I did not say that it can't be done. I said that the question can't be answered. The reason is that you have not provided **any facts to work from**. You mention a site but no url, you have not provided any analyzer output. It's like saying: *I want to go from A to B, but my car doesn't take me there! What's wrong?*. **I will gladly remove my downvote, if you edit the question to contain sufficient facts, that it can be answered**. Also be sure to click and read: [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: *how can you be sure that it can't be done when you do not have enough information* - How do you expect us to provide an answer when your own words say you've not provided us with **enough information** to use to do so?

Comment: Does the HTML `<form>` in question have a client-side script attached to it? I can imagine a scenario where the server generates a dynamic `loginKey` value when the HTML is served to the client, and then a script encodes the `pass` value with the `loginKey` when the form is submitted. If that is the case, you will have to replicate the same encoding behavior in your code when posting your login.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i was waiting for u :) , please look at the first post, i put some of the source html, please look at it, there is something like a onsubmit retrieve encrypt pass, can we use that ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, i parsed the loginKey right before the post and then instead of the pass provided by the site, i used my own pass and post the data and sent both of them  using idHttp.post() this time i was not redirected to error page, but to index which is the same fourm as login

Comment: @AliAhmadi: Yes, the `onsubmit` handler is the secret to making this work. When the form is submitted by a browser, the `encryptPassword()` function is called first to encrypt the password that gets submitted. You need to track down the code for that `encryptPassword()` function and port it into your code. You have not provided a real URL, so noone here can hunt down that code for you. You will have to study the HTML, look for any `<script>` tags and study their code until you find `encryptPassword()`. Chances are, it may be in an external JS/VBS file that you will have to download separately.

Comment: @AliAhmadi: also, if you are not already, make sure you are posting *every* `<input>` value that is not blank, especially the `hidden` values, not just the visible fields that the user fills in.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i have tried to post all possible combination of `encryptPassword()` as i am posting the other login parameters , but i have yet to succeed, how can i run the `encryptPassword` function ?, should i send an `onSubmit` parameter with value `encryptPassword('pass')` ?, i'm stuck, any suggestion will be appreciated. ( i should also mention that i didn't find any js/vbs file in the html source that is useful, am i looking at the wrong place ?)

Comment: @AliAhmadi I already told you earlier what to do. You need to locate the source code for `encryptPassword()` (it will either be in the HTML itself, or in an external file referenced by the HTML) and port it into your Delphi code. You cannot execute the original script with `TIdHTTP`, and you cannot submit it to the server. Since you will not provide the true URL, and have not provided the original script, noone here can help you with porting `encryptPassword()` to Delphi.